# Android: Change text in a Dialog

Tags: android

I am developping an app for Android, and I ran into a problem I am having difficulty to solve. Here is a simplified model of my app:

The main activity contains an image. When clicked, a dialog containing a `TextView` and a `Button` is shown.

When the button is clicked, it triggers `buttonClick(View v)` in the main activity.

`buttonClick` comes up with a number, which I'd like to set as the `TextView`'s text.

How can I change the text of a dialog's `TextView` from the main activity, without closing the dialog first?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post something what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dialog is a child of DialogFragment you can create a method in it which changes dialog 's textview text, or make a textview public (not recommended). You also should have a variable which contain dialog object instace.

I can try to tell you more if you will show the code of your dialog and activity.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. I created a method `update(String message)` in my custom Dialog class.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to do .. try like this

firstly you need to get ID of text view and Button as described below .. Then after you can do what ever you wish

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ConfirmCabsPage.this);

dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_alert_dialog);
dialog.setCancelable(false);

TextView tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textone);

Button btn = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        setTextValue(your_value); // This is your method in main class
    }
});

dialog.show();


public static void setTextValue(String your_value);
{
    tv.setText(your_value);
}
```

That's it .. you are good to go..